# Pentaho - Connecting to Carte using Thin Client

Tags: sql, jdbc, pentaho, kettle

I am hoping someone can point me in the right direction. We are looking to implement Kettle CE v5 and Carte Web Services. We are wanting to use the JDBC Thin Client within other applications to pull data from Kettle.

We have Carte setup bit we are finding that no data is coming through the JDBC thin client. It is connecting perfectly but it appears no table are available to clear.. At this stage I am using SQuirrel SQL Client to test the JDBC connection.

I am currently using this configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<slave_config>
    <slaveserver>
      <name>Server1</name>
      <port>80</port>
    </slaveserver>
    <repository>
      <name>Repo</name>
    </repository>   
    <services> 
        <service>    
          <name>Test</name>     
          <filename>C:/Test.ktr</filename>     
          <service_step>Working</service_step>   
        </service>
    </services>

</slave_config>
```

If I run: http://myhost.com/kettle/runTrans/?trans=Test the job will work correctly and can be found in the status section of Carte... I am just stuck on how I can to get the Service "Working" to appear via the JDBC thin client. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this](http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/EAI/The+Thin+Kettle+JDBC+driver), this functionality is only available to pentaho v5.0 ***Enterprise Edition*** and beyond.

Comment: For anyone else who every has this issue, it is now disabled in Community Edition. FYI it was previous available in a pre-release in v5.0.1M and its functionality specifically related to Carte that is disabled which prevents this from working.